# Night Jasmine leaves

Tags: houseplants

I am in Baltimore, MD. I just bought this jasmine (in a pot). Healthy for only 1 week. 2-3 little blooms fall after 3 days and then I noticed that leaves are turning yellow and falling. Today, I saw little white bugs over the leaves. I am so worried about it.

Should I start with diluted soap? What else? I do not have that much experience with plants. Can these bugs attack my lemon/Lime little sprouts?

I grow them from seeds and they are healthy so far. Any advise is so appreciated.
Thank you,

Comment: I am in Baltimore, MD. I just bought this jasmine (in a pot). Healthy for only 1 week. 2-3 little blooms fall after 3 days and then I noticed that leaves are turning yellow and falling. Today, I saw little white bugs over the leaves. I am so worried about it.
Should I start with diluted soap? What else? I do not have that much experience with plants. Can these bugs attack my lemon/Lime little sprouts?
I grow them from seeds and they are healthy so far. Any advice is so appreciated. 
Thank you,

Comment: Is it possible for you to add a photo please?